# Unmerge Vertex with Mirror Modifier On (Make Two Vertices from One at the Center?)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I'm trying to model a collar on a shirt, and I'm using the Mirror modifier. I have one vertex at the center; is there any way to "unmerge" it and create two vertices (for the points on the collar)?

[image: One vertice joins two lines at the Y-Axis]

I know there are other ways to get the effect I want (Knife tool and then deleting the vertex at the center) but I'm just curious to know if this is a feature.

Comment: If you are new to Blender, there is something you need to do after modelling. When you are finished with modelling, always remember to remove doubles in your entire mesh, before ever rendering. FYI, mirror modifier creates doubles.

Comment: When you want to merge vertrice, first remove doubles and then merge points. Optionally, you can remove doubles at regular intervals during modelling. I sometimes do that before merging vertrice.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what it is you are trying to do then all you need to do is temporarily uncheck the **Clipping** option in the **Mirror Modifier** menu Then you will be able to select that vertice and drag it away from the center line.

[image]

Comment: Clipping is a special case of Merge.

Answer (score 0):

If Mirror is not yet applied, as it is in your case, you just uncheck **Merge** , move the vertices away, check Merge again and apply the modifier.  As to your question: if you mean a feature on its own, with its own name, it's hard to call it one.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Rip](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html?highlight=rip#rip) a vertex.

Select the vertex you want. Press <kbd>V</kbd> and pull. Two disconneded vertices will be created out of the original.

[image]

From the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html?highlight=rip#vertex-tools):

> Rip creates a “hole” into a mesh by making a copy of selected vertices and edges, still linked to the neighbor non-selected vertices, so that the new edges are borders of the faces on one side, and the old ones, borders of the faces of the other side of the rip.
>
> Rip will only work when edges and/or vertices are selected. Using the tool when a face is selected (explicitly or implicitly), will return an error message “Cannot perform ripping with faces selected this way” If your selection includes some edges or vertices that are not “between” two faces manifold, it will also fail with message “No proper selection or faces include”.

Alternatively you can use [Rip Fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html?highlight=rip#rip-fill) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

[image]

> Rip fill works the same as the Rip tool above, but instead of leaving a hole, it fills in the gap with geometry.

Comment: As of Blender 2.8 (haven't tried it on any other version) It does not appear that you can rip a mirrored seam. If I select the mirror seam edge, and rip, nothing changes. They're still locked together by the 'clipping' thing on the Merge Modifier. I think you can just turn clipping/merge off in the merge modifier, though?